# Consular Processing for Green Card

Tags: visas, usa, colombian-citizens

I am currently at the last stage of my green card application. I sent out my I-485, I-140 and other documents on January 1st of this year. I would like to include my girlfriend to follow my application. I know that there is a consular processing option.

Can anyone explain what the process is for that, please?

She lives overseas and has only a B-1/B-2 visa. She is planning to come to the United States to take English courses for a couple months as well.

1. When is the right time to get married for her to include her in my application?
2. When does she need to be back in her country to finish the consular processing?

Comment: Which country are you from? It will help inform the advice.

Comment: I have a german passport and she has a colombian passport but resides in Spain. She applied for her spanish citizenship and it is under process.

Answer (score 1):

Denis,
I was in a similar situation as yours.
You should get married before your I-485 is approved. That should give her access to the same work based category as you instead of a family based grencard which may take years. there are even special situations where she could file adjustment of status (I-485) from B1/B2 status (no need to go back for consular processing).

I don't know all the rules well enough to tell you exactly when. I think you need to spend the money on a good immigration lawyer as soon as possible. If done right, you could both have your greencards before the end of the year, but it can take many years for her if you don't do the right steps soon enough.